# fix image as page background from the array list javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an image as a background for the html page if the user wants to change.So what I did is, I used input file type to access the local folder and I can also make them to select the image whatever they want. But now I want to how can I make the image which was selected by the user to make it fixed as the page backgroundImage. Here is my code.This is mostly like a **desktop background or smartphone wallpaper**.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Understanding File upload and File access Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "file" id = "files" name = "files[]" multiple></input>
    <output id = "list"></output>
</body>
<script src = "fileaccess.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

**fileaccess.js**

```
if(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob){
     alert("Yes, its supported in this browser");
}else{
     alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

function handleFileSelect(evt){
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var output = [];
    for(var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++){
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a',') - ',
                    f.size, 'bytes, last modified: ',
                    f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                     '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';

}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Please give some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate a `FileReader`, read the chosen image via `readAsDataURL()` and assign the resulting data url to `body.style.backgroundImage`.

If you want the user to chose a selection of the image, you need to load the file to an image or canvas element, then allow the user to select a part of the displayed image and finally copy the image selection to an off-screen canvas. You can then assign the canvas's data url to `body.style.backgroundImage`:

```js
function imageToBackground(image, x, y, width, height) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + canvas.toDataURL() + ")";
}

function readImage(file, image) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
    image.src = reader.result;
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

var file = document.getElementById("file");
var image = document.getElementById("image");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

file.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  if (file) readImage(file, image);
});

button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Todo: let the user chose the region
  imageToBackground(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file">
<image id="image">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Set as background">
```

You would now need to provide the user with a way to select a region of the loaded image. Either chose one of the many image cropping plugins available on the net or come up with your own implementation.

Comment: thanks, @le_m, and is there anyway we can select a particular from the image to set as background.

Comment: @RSN can select a particular what? You mean a particular image of multiple chosen ones?

Comment: a particular section from the image. sorry typing mistake

Comment: @RSN Yes, by copying a part of the loaded image to a canvas and then call `Canvas.toDataURL()`. Shall the selection be chosen dynamically by the user?

Comment: could you please add that code in the answer or please give me a reference link for that.

Comment: @RSN I can, but which part of the image do you want as the background? Shall that selection be chosen by the user?

Comment: yes, you are correct.You can imagine as we do in our smartphones when you try to add a section of image as the wallpaper.Once they choose a wallpaper they should be able to select a section or the full image.

Comment: @RSN I outlined the solution above; for the selection you would need to chose e.g. a jquery plugin or come up with your own solution depending on your needs.

Comment: i cant understand what it does?,I couldn't select something and you are saying that I have to use a jquery plugin to select a particular section of the image?, Then why we have to bound the image to canvas?,I'm sorry for asking too much of questions

Comment: @RSN I provided you with the code you need in order to a) load the file to an HTML image element and b) given an HTML image element and a selection, make that selection the body's background image. Now you need to come up with a way to let the user chose the selection. You might want to ask a new question if you don't know how to do that.

Comment: K, for selection I have to bind the image to a jquery plugin and then I have to bind back the selected section to the canvas. Correct?

Comment: @RSN You need to find or come up with an implementation that, given an HTML image element, allows the user to chose a region defined by x, y, width, height.

Comment: K, let me try and what else, thanks for your time, if I couldn't make it, let me post another question. Please help me then.